# MS Access Datatype definition/conversion for a linked HTML table containing monetary values

Tags: ms-access, xhtml, precision, type-conversion

I have an HTML file that contains monetary values with up to 5 decimal places of precision. I **do** have control over the structure/contents of the HTML file (and it is XML compliant). Currently, some of the numeric values include thousands separators:

```
<td>-123,456.789</td>
<td>123.456</td>
<!--A null is an empty TD element-->
<td></td>
```

I'd like to link to the file from Access, and for the data to be imported into a local table with fields having a **Decimal** data type, *without losing **any** precision.*

However, Access' Import Wizard (and IMEXColumn spec) doesn't offer a Decimal datatype, so I'm torn between the following approaches:

```
| Linked Column Type + Local Column Type + Type Conversion in Append query +
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------|
| Text               | Decimal           | Implicit Conversion             |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------|
| Text               | Decimal           | CDec() Conversion               |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------|
| Currency           | Decimal           | Implicit Conversion             |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------|
| Currency           | Decimal           | CDec() Conversion               |
+--------------------+-------------------+---------------------------------|
```

I'm currently leaning toward the `Text/CDec()` approach (with consideration of Null values). Is this going to be the safest and most efficient approach?

Comment: I think you should try and see what kind of data ends up in the database exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You should link as Text, then you can convert with CDec.

If you have Null values, this should do in your clean-up query:

```
Amount: IIf(IsNull([AmountText]),Null,CDec(Nz([AmountText],0)))
```